# FIX Reject message

Tags: quickfix

I am using quickFix lib and assume I use FileStoreFactory. Now I received a Reject message which only promises to give tag 45 (RefSeqNum). By using this RefSeqNum, how I can get RefSeqNum's message type?

Comment: This one is for QuickFIX/J, but I assume the same can be done in QuickFIX: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19930938/243373. This retrieves the rejected message, so once you have that you should be able to get the message type.

Comment: RefSeqNum is a reference of rejected message which hold value of  MsgSeqNum (34) of rejected message

Comment: @TT. link references not reachable, steps are as expected

Comment: thanks TT's comments. It should work for C++ QF also I believe.